# Here maps latitude and longitude

Tags: java, maps, latitude-longitude

I am trying to implement Here Maps in my application and for that I need to save latitude , longitude , Os version , browser type . 
Can anyone please suggest how to get all these parameters from a desktop browser and as far as I can understand I cannot use the geolocation api for as it is for google maps , not sure about this though ?

Comment: Do I understand correctly you want to get the location of the user? If so, look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Thanks for this but I require this for desktop application which may not have a GPS . What I want is to get the lat , long possibly from IP of the user .

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/ and discussion

Comment: Hi Jozef thanks for the answer . I have one more doubt , just like mobile applications have a GPS setting to get the user lat , long . Can we do this from browser end as well in Desktop application . Basically , can I get the user's lat/long from the browser of the user (like in chrome we get  pop up on many websites that this wants to get your location info (Allow/Deny) .